# How to search for **not** sharedWithMe with Google Drive API v3?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

According to the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) you can search on 'sharedWithMe' in the same way as 'trashed':

```
trashed      boolean    =, !=   Whether the file is in the trash or not.
sharedWithMe boolean    =, !=   Files that have been shared with the authorized user.
```

Queries like "trashed", "not trashed" and "trashed=false" all work as expected. Also "sharedWithMe" works.

However whats does not work is "not sharedWithMe" or "sharedWithMe=false". What is the right syntax or is this a bug?

Example: q=not+sharedWithMe

Error:

```
"domain": "global",
"reason": "invalid",
"message": "Invalid Value",
"locationType": "parameter",
"location": "q"
```

Comment: Going over the [same documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters), I noticed the '='' and '!='' for the 'sharedWithMe' field. So your "not sharedWithMe" must make use of '!='' just like in programming.

Comment: Yes, the same as trashed. But `sharedWithMe=false` does not work. I also tried `!sharedWithMe`. No luck either.

Answer (score 2):

I also believe this problem is a bug in the google drive API implementation.

I am working around this problem (in python) by using the "sharedWithMeTime"
attribute that I get back from each list request.
After I get back all the items (sharedWithMe or not),
I then test for whether sharedWithMeTime attribute exists in each item.
If not, then the item must be "not sharedWithMe", which is what I wanted to use
as the query, but was getting the error described by the OP.

Link to the python doc on list request is here:
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.files.html#list

Comment: This workaround may still have issues, as the result will include files that are visible to anyone on the domain (no sharedWithMeTime attribute), but are also not in "my Drive".

Comment: 'ownedByMe' is perhaps a decent indicator of the elusive "not sharedWithMe"

Comment: As written in a comment on a similar question, using `'me' in owners` could be a good alternative, at least for some