# Get more than 1000 files from Google Drive Api using batch request and nextPageToken in Java

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client, batch-request

Is it possible to get more than 1000 files from Google Drive Api using batch request and nextPageToken in Java ? Or maybe there is another solution to get large amount of files without nextPageToken using batch request in Java? Right now I'm getting only 460 files.

```
void prepareDataForGrid(final String rootFileName, UI ui) throws IOException {

    driveService = googleDriveUtils.getDriveService(ui);
    JsonBatchCallback<FileList> callback = new JsonBatchCallback<FileList>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileList fileList, HttpHeaders httpHeaders) throws IOException {
            files = fileList.getFiles(); // get only 460 files

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(GoogleJsonError googleJsonError, HttpHeaders httpHeaders) throws IOException {
            throw new IOException();
        }
    };

    var batch = driveService.batch();
    driveService.files().list()
            .setQ("trashed = false")
            .setSpaces("drive")
            .setFields("nextPageToken, files(name, id, size, parents, modifiedTime, mimeType, webViewLink, createdTime)")
            .setPageSize(1000)
            .setOrderBy("name")
            .queue(batch, callback);
    batch.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The maximum page size for the [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) method is 1000

[image]

If you want additional files you will need to use the nextPageToken in the response and add it to the pageToken of the following response.  As this is one request after another i see no way of doing this with batching.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So I must do it with DO/WHILE loop like in docs. Do you know why I'm getting only 460 files insted 1000 when I add parents into fields?

Comment: why add parents? parents is the parent folder.   If you just want to download everything in a nice directory structure.  I have something in C# you that might give you some insperation https://www.daimto.com/list-all-files-on-google-drive/

Comment: Yes I'am making a file explorer integrated with Google Drive Api. Here is scrennshot https://i.imgur.com/0peqeSM.png . I need root files and their childrens.

Comment: You might want to consider buffering everything and then sorting it locally,  it may turn out to be fewer requests then using Parent and iterating over the directories.

Comment: Yes all files are buffered locally by parents. Can you alse help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40578037/how-to-search-for-not-sharedwithme-with-google-drive-api-v3  ? I have the same problem. qerry parameter "sharedWithMe = false and trashed = false" returns invalid parameter value.